# Are there any denominations or Christian groups that teach the Bible is not inspired?

Tags: denomination-survey, inspiration, denomination

I know that there are a respectable number of denominations that hold to the idea that the scriptures aren’t innerant (free from error). But are there any that go as far as to teach that the scriptures aren’t inspired?

Comment: A 'respectable number' could mean a sizeable number. Or it could mean 'those within that number are respectable (whatever that might, qualitatively, mean)' I am not certain to which you refer. That you use the plural 'are' suggests you meant to say 'there is a number of respectable denominations'. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @NigelJ I disagree with denominations that say such things, but I think they have enough followers to not be considered “fringe”. All that’s to say, it’s not really relevant to my question

Comment: I'm not aware of any denominations that hold this view, but there are individual Christians who claim that much of the Bible is pseudepigraphy or forgery. Many seminaries even teach naturalistic assumptions about the origins of the Bible.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod *sigh* yea I figured. The closest would probably be the United church of Canada. While it’s founding documents are standard liberalism when it comes to theology, they have atheist pastors, and I wouldn’t be surprised if many of their pastors held that view.